# Parsing itunes library xml only for smart and user created playlists

Tags: xml-parsing, itunes

I am trying to parse *itunes music library xml* for *itunes 10*. The requirement is to parse only the *smart* and *user created* playlists and skip *Library, Music, Movies, Tv Shows.*

Smart playlists have *Smart Info* and *Smart Criteria*. Let say I have a user created playlist called Library and Music, how can I distinguish them from original *Library* and *Music* containing all my music?

```
<key>Playlists</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key><string>Library</string>
        <key>Master</key><true/>
        <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>893</integer>
        <key>Playlist Persistent ID</key><string>1BEAC6B526CA9EE0</string>
        <key>Visible</key><false/>
        <key>All Items</key><true/>
        <key>Playlist Items</key>
        <array>
        .....
        </array>
    </dict>
    ...
    ...
    <dict>
    <key>Name</key><string>Library</string>
    <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>1509</integer>
    <key>Playlist Persistent ID</key><string>8F9656FD7FC595B1</string>
    <key>All Items</key><true/>
    <key>Playlist Items</key>
    <array>
    ....
    </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The only major difference I see the '*Visible*' text.. *Master* is not available for *Music, Tv Shows*, so can not use it either. Am guessing there should be distinction possible based upon *playlist id* or *playlist persistent id*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with multiple possibilities, required result was obtained by excluding those playlists with one of the following 3 keys:

```
<key>Distinguished Kind</key>
<key>Master</key>
<key>Folder</key>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must exclude those with one of these Keys

```
<key>Distinguished Kind</key>
<key>Master</key>
```

Comment: +1 for the idea. You missed the key 'Folder' which contains songs for all playlists inside that folder